# Superstructure Cumulative Hierarchy question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I have a question on the universal set and cumulative hierarchy.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)#In_ordinary_mathematics) claims the universe can be:
$S_0 = X$ and $S_{n+1} = S_n \cup \mathcal P(S_n)$, where $\mathbb U = \cup_{i=1}^\infty S_i$ and $X$ contains the signs.  Then the hierarchy is $V_0 := \varnothing, V_{\beta+1} := \mathcal{P} (V_\beta), V_\lambda := \bigcup_{\beta < \lambda} V_\beta$.

Is the hierarchy used such that $S_0 = V_\lambda$?

Comment: You make reference to "Wiki claims..." could you provide a link with more information?

Comment: @AndrewL added wiki link